# How to "picture" a principal Poincare-bundle?

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, geometry

Let $(P,\pi,M)$ be a principal $ISO(1,3)$-bundle. I suppose that in local trivialisation, the total space should look like $M\times ISO(1,3)$, since the fibre is isomorphic to the structure group. It can be proven that the Poincare group can be written as the semi-direct product between $SO(1,3)$ and the group of translations $\mathbb R^{1,3}=ISO(1,3)/SO(1,3)$ (being normal in $ISO(1,3)$), where $ISO(1,3)/SO(1,3)$ is the coset space. We denote this with $ISO(1,3)=\mathbb R^{1,3}\rtimes SO(1,3)$. Hence, its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{iso}(1,3)$ can be written as the direct sum of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ and $\mathfrak t=\mathfrak{iso}(1,3)/\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$, i.e $\mathfrak{iso}=\mathfrak{so}\oplus \mathfrak t$. This means that a random Cartan connection $A$ in $P\otimes \mathfrak{iso}(1,3)$ can be decomposed to a connection $\omega\in P\otimes \mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ (known as the spin connection) and a "connection" $\theta\in P\otimes\mathfrak t$ (known as the vielbein or coframe).

We surely can think of $\mathfrak t$ as the representation vector space $V$, if-f we choose the Adjoint rep of the translation group only. Therefore, we can consider an associated (vector) bundle $(P_V,\pi',M)$, where the fibre is $\mathfrak t\equiv V$, but this is associated with an $\mathbb R^{1,3}$-bundle, not with the Poincare bundle. With that in mind, one can surely show that $\theta$ satisfies all criteria to be a soldering 1-form (as it should be). Here comes the question: Is it valid to picture the total space $P$ (in a local trivilization) as $M\times SO(1,3)\times\mathbb R^{1,3}$, i.e like a space with mixed fibres? Am I justified to conclude that, since the semi-direct product is still a product (where only one subgroup needs to be normal in the product group)? May I (in a sense) decompose the initial bundle into 2 "sub-bundles"?